# php-sql where option for selecting date range

Tags: php, mysql

In my php page I create a drop down to select either `all` or a select all data greater than X number of days ago, say `10`. Im looking for a simplified way to run my query instead of what I have done.

What I have created is, this works I am just seeing if there is an option to simplify this query:

```
if($dropDownInput == 'All'){
   $db_query = mysqli_query("SELECT Name, MAX(Date), SUM(Iteratitions)
                             FROM my_table
                             GROUP BY Name, Date")
} else{
   $db_query = mysqli_query("SELECT Name, MAX(Date), SUM(Iteratitions)
                             FROM my_table
                             WHERE Date >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL $range day)
                             GROUP BY Name, Date")
}
```

Comment: Your queries looks fine but usage of `max(date)` is redundant when you already include it in group by it could be select name,date,...

Comment: I would try and extract the common SQL and add in the condition if required.  Easier to maintain common SQL than 2 copies of the same code.

Comment: you query looks fine, if you still want to simplify this extract common sql "SELECT Name, MAX(Date), SUM(Iteratitions) FROM my_table" and assign it to a variable which then can be concatenated with WHERE clause

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
$sql = SELECT Name, MAX(Date), SUM(Iteratitions)
                         FROM my_table
if($dropDownInput != 'ALL'){
    $sql.= " WHERE WHERE Date >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL $dropDownInput day)
}
$sql.="GROUP BY Name, Date"

$db_query = mysqli_query($sql)
```